# When was the upper and lower casing string substitution introduced into Bash?

Tags: bash

Bash offers the `${PATH,,}` and `${PATH^^}` in its more recent incarnations to change a the case of a variable value ad hoc. When were those introduced? The Bash Cookbook from 2007 does not make any mention of that string substitution and it is not listed on the [Bash Hackers Wiki page](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges).

Makes me think it was introduced with 4.x in 2009, but I'm looking for an authoritative source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They were introduced in `bash` 4.0, as indicated in the [`NEWS`](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS) file:

> This is a terse description of the new features added to `bash-4.0` since
>   the release of `bash-3.2`.  As always, the manual page (`doc/bash.1`) is
>   the place to look for complete descriptions.
>
> [...]
>
> hh. There are new case-modifying word expansions: uppercase (`^[^]`) and
>       lowercase (`,[,]`).  They can work on either the first character or
>       array element, or globally.  They accept an optional shell pattern
>       that determines which characters to modify.  There is an optionally-
>       configured feature to include capitalization operators.